# How to keep the Quill Rich Text Editor toolbar intact when creating a content change function with <select> <option>?

Tags: laravel, templates, laravel-8, quill

I'm doing a small project on choosing templates for emails using Laravel 8. I use the Quill Rich Text Editor library to create built-in email template editing functionality. My idea is to use  and  to select email templates. However, I cannot keep Quill's toolbar when choosing other options. Here are pictures on the website:

[Here is a picture of my idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkA7n.png).

[For example when I select `sorry content`, the Quill toolbar disappeared](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6dLy.png)

```
//here is my HTML's code in Laravel's View file:
<table class="tg-tab" border="1">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="width: 20% !important;">{{ __('label.stayroom.test_email') }}</td>
                                        <td class='word-break'>
                                            <p><input type="text" id="test_email_address" placeholder="input@your_email"></p>
                                            <p><button id="btn_send_test_email">{{ __('label.stayroom.send_test_email_btn') }}</button></p>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="width: 20% !important;">{{ __('label.stayroom.title_preview') }}</td>
                                        <td class='word-break'>
                                            <p><input type="text" id="title_content" placeholder="input@your_title"></p><br>

                                           <p></p><br>
                                            <div><select name="list" id="contentSelector"  >
                                                    <option value="">Select content</option>
                                                    <option value="sorry">sorry content</option>
                                                    <option value="thank">thank content</option>
                                                    <option value="confirm">Confirm content</option>
                                            </select></div>

                                        </td>
                                        {{-- new --}}
                                        <td class='word-break' rowspan="2" >
                                            <div class="scrollable-container">
                                            <h2>List</h2>
                                            <div class="scrollable-div">
                                               @include('stayroom.button_previewEmail')
                                            </div>
                                          </div>
                                        </td>
                                        {{-- new --}}
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="width: 20% !important;" >{{ __('label.stayroom.index.preview_email') }}</td>
                                           <td class='word-break' id="newContent">
                                            <div id="editor">
                                                {!! $content !!}
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <input type="hidden" id="saveContent" value="">

                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
```

```
//here is my JS's code:
{{-- QUILL --}}
<script src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <script type="text/javascript" >

//QUILL toolbar:
 let toolbaroption=[
        ["bold","italic","underline","strike"],
        [{indent:"+1"},{indent:"-1"}],
        [{align:[]}],
        [{size:["small",false,"large","huge"]}],
        ["image","link","video"],
        [{color:[]},{background:[]}],

    ];
    var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
        modules:{
            toolbar: toolbaroption,
        },
      theme: 'snow'
    });

 // select option
    let contentSelector = document.getElementById('contentSelector');
    let initialDelta = quill.getContents();


    contentSelector.addEventListener('change', function() {
    let selectedValue = this.value;
    let newContent = document.getElementById("newContent");

    if (selectedValue === 'sorry') {
        newContent.innerHTML = 'Sorry';
    } else if (selectedValue === 'thank') {
        newContent.innerHTML = 'Thank!';
    } else if (selectedValue === 'confirm') {
        newContent.innerHTML = {!! json_encode($content) !!};
    }

  });
```

I was trying to display the value of the  and with the last  (`Confirm content`) I was able to display the original text. However, Quill's toolbar has not been retained. Where did I go wrong? Looking forward to your guidance.
My English is not very good, I will try to express my ideas as best as possible.